# Can I use CodeIgniter 4 with PHP 7.2?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

As mentioned on the CodeIgniter 4 [Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/intro/requirements.html), that it required PHP 7.3 or newer. But, when trying to install with composer on PHP 7.2, the framework can be installed and running with `php spark serve` command.

I just want to make sure that can I use CodeIgniter 4 with PHP 7.2 without any problems?

Note: currently I can't update the PHP version on my server.

Comment: Both the documentation and the composer.json say that 7.3 is required. Even if it seems to work, you're not going to get any support. As 7.2 is past end of life and 7.3 is approaching end of life, I wouldn't start a new project on either of them. With the cheap and easy availability of containers, container hosting services, and virtual machines, "I can't update by server" isn't really a legit argument these days.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thanks for the comment, so if I still need to using CodeIgniter 4, I must use PHP 7.3 or newer right?

Comment: Yes. It's not worth the effort to try with 7.2. Even if you succeed, you'll have an already outdated system.

Comment: Thank you, answered my confusion.

Comment: If you're on the latest version of CI4 you can even go to PHP 8